# Read access table into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access

I'm trying to read an Access table into a pandas dataframe and am a relative newbie.  The name of the file/table are:

1. Name of MS Access file: test.mdb
2. table Name: MA MEMBERSHIP COMBINED CAP REPORT

I've trying the pandas_access package w/o luck.  Code I tried is below:

```
import pandas_access as mdb
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df = mdb.read_table("test.mdb", "MA MEMBERSHIP COMBINED CAP REPORT 2018")
```

Table I'm reading is about 700 MB.  Would appreciate any suggestions?

-Joe

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more details. What operating system are you using? What happens when you try and run your code? If you get a traceback (stack trace), add it to your question in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks Gord.   I'm using window 7 Enterprise 64 bit version.   My error is finally:
    999                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.  Despite this error the file exists in the same folder as my program.

Comment: Why are you using this module if you are on Windows? This seems to only be useful for Mac/Linux users. Simply use `pyodbc` and pandas' `read_sql`.

Comment: @JoeMoss - Are you running 32-bit Python? If you're not sure you can run `import struct; print("running as {0}-bit".format(struct.calcsize("P") * 8))`

Comment: @ Gord Thompson I'm running 64 bit 3.6 Python thru an Anaconda distribution.

Comment: @JoeMoss - Does your machine have Microsoft Office installed? If so, is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: (p.s. the space after @ is breaking reply notifications. Just use @Parfait ...)

Comment: @Gord Thompson I have 32-bit Office installed.  Thank for the tip on notifications:)

Comment: @Parfait - I'll try code with pyodbc w/ read_sql to run. Appreciate the comments. –

Answer (score 1):

As a start, use your actual database, and bracket the table name:

```
df = mdb.read_table("BlueCap MA txt files 2018.mdb", "[MA MEMBERSHIP COMBINED CAP REPORT 2018]")
```

Comment: My apologies. While troubleshooting I played around with naming conventions in case that would help and renamed a copy of the access file "test" from the original name.  Corrected the text of my question above.

Comment: OK. Then add the full _drive\path_ to the filename.